# Javascript - Obter Filepath do Google Docs

Tags: javascript, html, google

Boa tarde pessoal!

Talvez alguém já tenha trabalhado com o Google docs (g-suite) e possa dar uma ideia com este problema.

A empresa vai migrar do office para o g-suite, logo, todos os documentos e planilhas estarão online.

Nós temos um sistema de produtividade que mapeia os nomes dos arquivos (**FileName**) acessados bem como seus caminhos de rede (**Filepath**), para saber se os usuários estão trabalhando com o que devem trabalhar.

Bem, dentro do g-suite da google, não temos como buscar algumas informações automaticamente, mas podemos usar o Javascript para trazer a informação quando o usuário acessa, por exemplo, quando o usuário abre um documento, eu identifico pela URL que se trata de algo no google docs e busco com um comando o nome do arquivo:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('docs-title-input')[0].value
```

O problema está em encontrar o **Filepath**, ou seja, as pastas e subpastas dentro do drive onde este arquivo está armazenado. Já estou faz 2 dias tentando encontrar uma maneira de trazer isso, mas não encontro pois creio que o código da página não o disponibiliza (não, não tenho certeza e não, não sou expert em Javascript).

Se alguém já viu alguma situação como essa, agradeço qualquer ajuda.